# Batch menu and submenu

Tags: batch-file, syntax

so i am trying to build a little menu with submenu that i can use for simple stuff, such as opening default router address, open control panel, network connections, etc, the first submenu works, the second submenu, no matter what option you choose, it closes the command prompt, i can't see a syntax error, the code is not finished so there are uncompleted menus, i am not a savvy with cmd commands so any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
 @ECHO off 

:start 
CLS 
ECHO Welcome, %USERNAME%! 
echo. 
echo Main Menu
echo. 
echo 1. Network Utilities
echo 2. Display Submenu 2 
echo 3. Display Submenu 3 
echo 4. Shutdown
echo 5. Restart
echo 6. Log Off
echo 7. Exit this Menu

set /p choice="Enter your choice: " 
if "%choice%"=="1" goto submenu_1 
if "%choice%"=="2" goto submenu_2 
if "%choice%"=="3" goto submenu_3 
if "%choice%"=="4" shutdown -t 20
if "%choice%"=="5" shutdown -r
if "%choice%"=="6" shutdown -l
if "%choice%"=="7" goto bail 

:submenu_1 
echo Submenu_1 
ECHO    
ECHO 1 - Open Router Config 192.168.0.1
ECHO 2 - Open Router Config 192.168.100.1
ECHO 3 - Open Router Config 192.168.254.1
ECHO 4 - Show Network Config
ECHO 5 - Open Control Panel
ECHO 6 - Open Network And Sharing Center
ECHO 7 - Open Add or Remove Apps
ECHO 8 - Show All Network Devices
ECHO 0 - Back to Main Menu
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 start HTTP://192.168.0.1
IF %M%==2 start HTTP://192.168.100.1
IF %M%==3 start HTTP://192.168.254.1
IF %M%==4 ipconfig /all
IF %M%==5 start control
IF %M%==6 start control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter
IF %M%==7 start appwiz.cpl
IF %M%==8 NET VIEW
IF %M%==0 goto start
goto submenu_1


:submenu_2 
echo Submenu_2 
ECHO    
ECHO 1 - Show Disk Space
ECHO 2 - Disk Defrag and Cleanup
ECHO 0 - Back to Main Menu
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 0, then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 
IF %M%==2 call Disk_Defrag_and_Cleanup.bat
IF %M%==0 goto start
goto submenu_2


:submenu_3 
echo Submenu_3 
set /p menu_choice="Would you like to run this submenu again (Y) ? " 
if "%menu_choice%"=="Y" goto submenu_3 

:bail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
IF %M%==1
```

With nothing after the comparison, this is a syntax error, and is causing cmd to error parsing your batch file, and abort.  To fix, put a command after `%M%==1`, or simply remove that line.

As a more general debugging note, **please remove `@echo off` from the top of your file when debugging**.  If you run into a simple syntax error like this, CMD will show you *exactly* where the problem is, *as long as you don't disable all debug information at the top of your file*.  When you release the script to production, you can disable echo.

Comment: awesome! thank you, also, how can i execute a batch from a batch file? on my submenu_2 i am trying to execute another batch file but i get an error saying that is not a recognized command, i am using the call command, anything else i should use ?

Comment: nvm, apparently the bat file can't have spaces or underscore, when i change the name to a simple name with no spaces, it works

Comment: @Wolf - You could also put the name with spaces in quotes.